# Python: wait for requests_futures.sessions to finish before continuing with the code flow

Tags: python, python-requests

My current code as it stands prints an empty list, how do I wait for all requests and callbacks to finish before continuing with the code flow?

```
from requests_futures.sessions import FuturesSession
from time import sleep

session = FuturesSession(max_workers=100)

i = 1884001540 - 100
list = []
def testas(session, resp):
    print(resp)
    resp = resp.json()
    print(resp['participants'][0]['stats']['kills'])
    list.append(resp['participants'][0]['stats']['kills'])
while i < 1884001540:
    url = "https://acs.leagueoflegends.com/v1/stats/game/NA1/" + str(i)
    temp = session.get(url, background_callback=testas)
    i += 1
print(list)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From looking at session.py in requests-futures-0.9.5.tar.gz its necesssary to create a future in order to wait for its result as shown in this code:

```
from requests_futures import FuturesSession

session = FuturesSession()
# request is run in the background
future = session.get('http://httpbin.org/get')
# ... do other stuff ...
# wait for the request to complete, if it hasn't already
response = future.result()
print('response status: {0}'.format(response.status_code))
print(response.content)
```

As shown in the README.rst a future can and should be created for every session.get() and waited on to complete.

This might be applied in your code as follows starting just before the while loop:

```
future = []
while i < 1884001540:
    url = "https://acs.leagueoflegends.com/v1/stats/game/NA1/" + str(i)
    future.append(session.get(url, background_callback=testas)
    i += 1
for f in future:
    response = f.result()
    # the following print statements may be useful for debugging
    # print('response status: {0}'.format(response.status_code))
    # print(response.content, "\n")
print(list)
```

I'm not sure how your system will respond to a large number (1884001440) of futures and another way to do it is by processing them in smaller groups say 100 or 1000 at a time.  It might be wise to test the script with a relatively small number of them at the beginning to find out how fast they return results.

Comment: Could you  show how that would look like with my code? I just started getting into asynchronous stuff so I have hard time getting my head around this.

Comment: Added some example code in answer.  Not sure how it will work.  Best to start with a small number of session.gets and hence Futures to see how fast they respond.

Answer (score -1):

from here https://pypi.python.org/pypi/requests-futures it says

```
from requests_futures.sessions import FuturesSession

session = FuturesSession()
# first request is started in background
future_one = session.get('http://httpbin.org/get')
# second requests is started immediately
future_two = session.get('http://httpbin.org/get?foo=bar')
# wait for the first request to complete, if it hasn't already
response_one = future_one.result()
```

so it seems that `.result()`  is what you are looking for